# What is "Section 508" very very simply?

Tags: accessibility, section508

I researched at google and found many confusing, looooong explanations for Section 508! made me even more confused.

**very simply, what is this Section 508?**

Answer (score 12):

A fairly simple explanation can be found [here](http://searchcio.techtarget.com/sDefinition/0,,sid182_gci914785,00.html); summed up nicely by this snippet:

> Section 508, an amendment to the
>   United States Workforce Rehabilitation
>   Act of 1973, is a federal law
>   mandating that all electronic and
>   information technology developed,
>   procured, maintained, or used by the
>   federal government be accessible to
>   people with disabilities. Technology
>   is deemed to be "accessible" if it can
>   be used as effectively by people with
>   disabilities as by those without.

[This page](http://www.evengrounds.com/articles/what-is-section-508) also offers another good, simple explanation:

> Section 508, in simple terms, requires
>   that when Federal Agencies develop,
>   procure, maintain or use electronic
>   and information technology,
>   information and data should be
>   accessible to people with disabilities.

Obviously there's lots more involved in this process, but you already knew that. Hopefully this clarifies things a little bit!

Answer (score 6):

From [A Website for Lawyers](https://awebsiteforlawyers.com/7-facts-about-web-design/):

> What is Section 508 Accessibility Law?
>
> Section 508 of the Rehabilitation Act
> of 1973, is a US law requiring the
> federal government to make all goods
> and services-including web sites and
> intranets fully accessible to people
> with disabilities. It identifies
> specific standards for Internet and
> Web accessibility, which are often
> used as a basis for evaluating whether
> or not Web sites meet accessibility
> requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I gave a talk about this at the last PyCon:

http://djangocon.blip.tv/file/3261238/

508 compliance is about making your site accessible to everyone, no matter their handicap. While much of 508 is focused on people using screen readers, you also have to consider those that are physically handicapped (and may have trouble mousing over tiny areas), or those that are deaf (and would love to play your Flash game, but can't hear the beeps required to win!).

Answer (score -2):

The idea is the following: unless your product is fully Section 508 compliant you may be unable to your product sell to the US Government organizations.